# Difference between Jordan decomposition and Eigenvalue decomposition (Spectral decomposition theorem).

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know what are differences between Jordan decomposition and Spectral decomposition theorem (Eigenvalue decomposition). Is main difference that for Eigenvalue decomposition P - matrix with eigenvectors have to be orthonormal?

Comment: A complex matrix might not have an eigenvalue decomposition but always a jordan decomposition. Also in case an eigenvalue decomposition exists, notice that the eigenspaces to different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other if and only if the matrix is normal.

Answer (score 4):

The spectral decomposition in the "spectral decomoposition theorem" is a *special kind* of eigenvalue decomposition in which the $P$-matrix is orthogonal (which is to say that the eigenvectors are orthonormal).  An eigenvalue decomposition is a special kind of Jordan decomposition in which the "Jordan form" matrix is diagonal.

Every square matrix has a Jordan decomposition.  Every diagonalizable matrix has an eigenvalue decomposition.  Every normal matrix has a spectral decomposition.

Comment: Would be great if for completeness you also mention the relation to singular value decomposition even though I know the question did not ask about it.

Comment: @pevogam If there's a question that you have about singular value decomposition, then maybe you should ask it

Comment: Nothing in particular on my side, I just thought that it would complete your already very straightforward comparison for others that bump into this page. But thanks for replying.